# Best practices for creating layouts (using server-side code)

Tags: jquery, html, css, server-side, frontend

Lets assume for the sake of this question, I have a container element, with three columns inside that container and with a right margin of 10 pixels, on the third column I want to set the right margin to 0 pixels.

Now  there are two ways I can do this, I can do this using jquery to select the nth-child, but I can also do this server-side using a simple loop count to get the third element. My question is what is the recommended practice of achieving something like this? Doing it server side means, the layout works perfect even if javascript is disabled on the users browser. However, the idea of using server side code for these kind of cosmetic reasons, may not be ideal practice, and server-side could should be used strictly for functionality.

I'd like to know what peoples views are on this.

Comment: You seem to be working with a false dichotomy, client-side vs server-side. What about using CSS for presentation?

Comment: In general I use CSS for presentation, but there are cases like the above example, where I cannot use CSS, so it is either JQuery or server-side. Another example would be if I want to add class names particular to items. I could do this very easily in JQuery but if the user has javascript disabled, then it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

What about using CSS `:last-child`?

```
#container div:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

If you really care about IE6, you can add some kind of class (like `final-column`) in the server-side code for the last column, but no inline styles.

```
#container div:last-child, #container div.final-column { margin-right: 0; }
```

Finally, don't use Javascript for styling purposes.

Comment: What about every third item in the list? I could use the css nth-child pseudo class but it does not work in IE.

Comment: As I wrote, if you want to worry about old browsers, you can add classes on the serverside.

Comment: Ok, so I should generally not use JQuery for these kind of layout corrections? Just as I assumed.

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is not gonna be changed after rendered, I believe using server-side HTML generation should be a more robust way.

Comment: Yes, thats the thing its a more robust way, but it also means lots of messy server side code.